# SelectList not being populated

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a registration form uses a ViewModel called registerViewModel. I am trying to add a dropdown that will allow the user to select a grade. The grade data should come from a model called 'GradeMatrix'

In my Account controller I have the following -

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
        {
            PopulateGradeDropDownList(viewModel.GradeID);
```

I also have -

```
private void PopulateGradeDropDownList(object selectedGrade = null)
        {
            var gradeQuery = from d in db.GradeMatrix
                             orderby d.GradeName
                             select d;

            ViewBag.GradeID = new SelectList(gradeQuery, "GradeID", "GradeName", selectedGrade);

        }
```

and in my view I have -

@Html.DropDownList("GradeID", string.Empty)

When I click on my Register link I get the following error -

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'GradeID'.
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The view code should be:

```
@Html.DropDownList(string.Empty, (SelectList)ViewBag.GradeID)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me a different error -  'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TRS.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownList' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Thanks again, but that gives me Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name